# surf in two listviews and lost focused

Tags: focus, google-tv, listviewitem, android-listfragment, d-pad

I have one fragment activity include two list fragments.
I use D-pad to moving through lists.
For example, when I click on **listview1->tv**, in **listview2** shows tv channels 
. When I click **listview1->movie**, in **listview2** shows movies list and so on.

So this is my problem: when I click **listview1->item3** (**item3** is highlighted now by a selector) and go to **listview2** and use d-pad up/down to surf the items then I come back to **listview1**, by left arrow key, I expect to going back to **listview->item3**. But it's not the case and I can't gust witch item in **listview1** will focused (highlighted)

I can't handle the focused item, I need to go back to last selected item (`getListView().getSelectedItemPosition()`) has true item position number but focused/hilighted is not in true/last postion)

Android 2.3.4

I used these methods but none worked

```
getListView().setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean focused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!focused) allowfocus=true;
        if (focused && allowfocus){
            getListView().setSelection(PosHolder.MENU_LAST_POS);
                    OR 
            getListView().setSelection(getListView().getSelectedItemPosition());
                    OR
            getListView().getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
                    OR
            getListView().getSelectedView().requestFocus();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Menu Got Focused:"+ getListView().getSelectedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to create a customListView which inherits from the original ListView, and then override the OnFocusChange Event to handle your focus in there.

Comment: I was in the same situation and this worked perfectly for me. Thanks!